# Is there a resource that lists online travel search engines by the trustworthiness of their listed final prices?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, price

I tried to book a travel recently and used a price agregagator to compare values. I know often the listed prices still have extra fees on top.

I picked the best price and read the travel agency conditions and all seemed fine. They clearly state that there were no fees or taxes. The final step though revealed prohibitive costs. There was an extra charge for credit card, debit card, etc.

The commission was around €150. This made the price much higher than that of other companies in the end. The problem, besides bad publicity, is that you only get this information in the last step.

I always try to find reviews but these tend to be negatively biased and are often inaccurate and don't necessarily reflect this kind of problems.

Is there a website or resource that list travel agencies and these commissions and practices?

Comment: In which country is this? Are you talking about a search engine/aggregator or a travel agent? Are you sure this is about taxes rather than fees or even simply a change in price after being redirected to another website? Credit card charges are not uncommon, but that's typically €2-5! Also, if other agencies have similar commissions, the price might not be that unattractive, at the end of the day there might be no alternative but to compare them one-by-one.

Comment: Hi @relaxed, this is an Internet travel agency. I have no idea which country they are based on. They have translations to several languages. If that is of interest I am in Europe. I am talking about searching in an agregator and than picking a price and going to the on line travel agent directly.

Comment: So you really mean the price discrepancy between the aggregator and the travel agency?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with taxes *per se* but it's an interesting question. I took the liberty of editing the title and question to make it a bit clearer, please let me know if that's OK or roll it back if it's not.

Comment: I still can't quite make out what you mean by “Everything card processing had taxes.” Also, the problem might be that they write “no taxes” to trick you in thinking the price will stay the same, whereas they will add other fees at the end. A commission is a fee added by the agent, not a tax collected by the government so it might be technically true (albeit highly misleading) to say that there were no “taxes”.

Comment: By tax I mean comission. But the agency uses that term no "agency taxes". It's like you go to the supermarket with the cheapest milk and when you check out they say, well we have a tax over the transaction. It's not their tax, fee or comission. It's the processing fee for the transaction. They "blame" a third party although you know standard transaction fees are not that high.

Comment: Why book through travel agencies? Websites like Kayak.com have 0 hidden fees.

Comment: @JonathanReez Technically, Kayak *is* a travel agent. Traditionally, they get their commission from the provider, it's not charged separately to the customer. But apparently the one nsn used is different.

Comment: @nsn Note that in the US, supermarkets do publish prices that do not include the local sales tax, which is then added at check-out. Not saying it's good for the customer but expectations do vary and I think it's somewhat important to be specific about what we are talking about. In any case, it's a good question and hopefully someone will be able to provide an answer!

Comment: @Relaxed maybe not the best example than, but the situation I describe goes beyond that.

Comment: @JonathanReez  - Kayak seems an agregator. At least I allways end up in another website when I search through them.

Comment: @nsn yeah, but they usually list the full price and you don't have to worry about whatever information does the other website list on their search engine.

Comment: @JonathanReez ah, but happened to me is that they listed the full price and than in the end I got extra 150 euros of transaction costs (visa)

Comment: There is a computational cost for a travel agent (such as Expedia) to check current prices. Therefore there is a strong tendency to cache the prices until checkout.

Comment: @Calchas I am peerfectly aware of that. But that is not the problem. Maybe I was not clear. The price that I got in the travel agent website was exactly the price that was announced in the price agregator.  I wouldnt call that just a coicidence. The problem was with the final (abusive) processing fees.

Comment: @nsn. I see. In this case it might be useful to go directly to the airline and purchase the tickets from there.  I am not aware of a list of fees imposed by travel agents.

Comment: @Calchas true, but travel agents often have access to better prices and may give you a better deal. Some can even give up of part of their comission to offer a better price. The problem is that lately many online agents offer "great" prices at the expense of hidden fees. This  VISA processing commission seems clearly the case.

Answer (score 1):

Usually right now there is no such website, Some website seems to show various rate and compare option however not as much useful for people.I think better option will be you opt manually searching few most reputed website for this as they will be much beneficial as compared to the comparing ones. I am sure you will get the better search result and reviews if you go manually.